Dagger Hilt : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList
I am trying dagger hilt, and trying to resolve this error for past 2 days, none works
I am still stuck. I am using the new version gradle( version=8.6) which is little confusing for me.
error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.test2dagcln.CoinApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.test2dagcln.CoinApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.test2dagcln-GhkXDfUqFpRj-HO3VSzjOA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.test2dagcln-GhkXDfUqFpRj-HO3VSzjOA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /product/lib]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1232)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6574)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.test2dagcln.CoinApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.test2dagcln-GhkXDfUqFpRj-HO3VSzjOA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.test2dagcln-GhkXDfUqFpRj-HO3VSzjOA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:51)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1155)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6574) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:235) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/test2dagcln/Hilt_CoinApplication;
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.test2dagcln.Hilt_CoinApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.test2dagcln-GhkXDfUqFpRj-HO3VSzjOA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.test2dagcln-GhkXDfUqFpRj-HO3VSzjOA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:230)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 17 more

build.gradle.kts(app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.test2dagcln"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.test2dagcln"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

    // Compose dependencies
    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
    implementation (libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
    implementation (libs.accompanist.flowlayout)

    // Coroutines
    implementation (libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
    implementation (libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation (libs.hilt.android)
    annotationProcessor (libs.hilt.android.compiler)
    implementation (libs.androidx.hilt.lifecycle.viewmodel)
    annotationProcessor (libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)
    implementation (libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)

    // Retrofit
    implementation (libs.retrofit)
    implementation (libs.converter.gson)
    implementation (libs.okhttp)
    implementation (libs.logging.interceptor)
}

libs.version.toml
[versions]
accompanistFlowlayout = "0.17.0"
agp = "8.4.0"
converterGson = "2.9.0"
hiltAndroid = "2.49"
hiltAndroidCompiler = "2.49"
hiltCompiler = "1.2.0"
hiltLifecycleViewmodel = "1.0.0-alpha03"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
kotlinxCoroutinesCore = "1.7.3"
kotlinxCoroutinesAndroid = "1.7.3"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.0"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2023.08.00"
hilt="2.49"
loggingInterceptor = "5.0.0-alpha.2"
navigationCompose = "2.7.7"
okhttp = "5.0.0-alpha.2"

[libraries]
accompanist-flowlayout = { module = "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout", version.ref = "accompanistFlowlayout" }
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-hilt-compiler = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltCompiler" }
androidx-hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel", version.ref = "hiltLifecycleViewmodel" }
androidx-hilt-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "hiltCompiler" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose", version.ref = "navigationCompose" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-compose = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
converter-gson = { module = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson", version.ref = "converterGson" }
hilt-android-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroidCompiler" }
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
kotlinx-coroutines-android = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android", version.ref = "kotlinxCoroutinesAndroid" }
kotlinx-coroutines-core = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core", version.ref = "kotlinxCoroutinesCore" }
logging-interceptor = { module = "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor", version.ref = "loggingInterceptor" }
okhttp = { module = "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp", version.ref = "okhttp" }
retrofit = { module = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit", version.ref = "converterGson" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }


build.gradle(project)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false
}

settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Test2DagCln"
include(":app")
 

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".CoinApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test2DagCln"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Test2DagCln">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

CoinApplication
@HiltAndroidApp
class CoinApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("Test", "CoinApplication found!")
    }
}


Is there a reason you're still using annotationProcessor and not kapt?

earlier that was kapt and then i saw somthing over internet saying this might resolve so i did that but that didn't help
